# Comparing numeric and integer values sometimes gives TRUE and sometimes FALSE

Tags: r, integer, numeric

I use `%in%` to compare two lists, one with a vector of *numeric* values and the other with *corresponding integer* values. The result is really weird; sometimes `TRUE` and sometimes `FALSE` and I can't figure out why.

For example the code below gives `TRUE`

```
list(c(1, 1)) %in% list(c(1L, 1L))
```

However, if we change the second number in the vectors to 2 and 2L we get `FALSE`

```
list(c(1, 2)) %in% list(c(1L, 2L))
```

Changing the second number to 3 or 4 gives `TRUE` again.

```
list(c(1, 3)) %in% list(c(1L, 3L))
list(c(1, 4)) %in% list(c(1L, 4L))
```

Using some other values again produces `FALSE` but I can't see any pattern to this. For example using 8 and 9 results in `FALSE`:

```
list(c(8, 9)) %in% list(c(8L, 9L))
```

Does anyone know why this is the case? It's really baffling and I'm completely lost why it's happening.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bit tricky. `%in%` is implemented using `match()` (printing `` `%in%` `` shows `match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) > 0L`), and `?match` says

> Factors, raw vectors and lists are converted to character vectors

before comparison.  Now let's compare:

- `as.character(list(c(1,1)))` is "c(1,1)" (and the same for the integer equivalent)
- `as.character(list(c(1,2)))` is "c(1,2)"
- **but** ... `as.character(list(c(1L, 2L)))` is "1:2" (!), because R recognizes a contiguous integer sequence as one that can be collapsed to an alternative/compact representation (ALTREP)

(As another example, `as.character(list(7L, 8L, 9L))` is "7:9", not "c(7, 8, 9)")

As a workaround, you could explicitly convert the vectors with `as.numeric()` ...

You could also (as suggested by @user2554330) add a class attribute to your lists (`class(L) <- c("mylist", "list")`) and define a `mtfrm.mylist` method to do the coercion-to-numeric-before-character stuff in a slightly more principled way ...

Comment: +10 for bringing in the `as.character` link, I had stiff-armed that in my research

Comment: Adding a class to the lists would let you change the comparison method by defining a `mtfrm` method for the class.

Comment: Wow, awsome, this explains it! Thanks.
The `as.numeric()` workaround works.

Comment: If this solves your problem/answers your question, you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it.